# show error message in angular's bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ typeahead in my application. I have a requirement whenever any special character is typed or no response came for search string then message has to be shown in suggestion like 'special Character not allowed', 'No results found' etc. . I have handled this case but anything that I return in string becomes a selectable property which is a normal behavior. I want to restrict user to select this message. please help me how to handle this scenario. Any jsFiddle is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance